# Use backpressure mechanics to fetch data with paging

Tags: rx-java

I am trying to use backpressure to handle data paging. I have an observable which requests N new chunks of data from server for every request(N). I wish to fetch a new chunk of data after user clicks a button.

My main goal is to replace this api by Observable contract

```
interface Api {
    void openConnection();  //subscription
    boolean hasNextPage();  //completion
    Single<Data> nextPage();//onNext and onError
    void closeConnection(); //unsubscription
}
```

I am think that zip would be great here

```
Observable.zip(dataFromServer(), userActions(), (data, ø) -> data).subscribe(showData());
```

But because of RxRingBuffer with the size of M inside the zip operator the upper construction after subscription immediately requests M chunks of data from the server. This is totally inappropriate. Even if I could change the buffer size to 1 (but I can't) the behavior of the upper construction is inapropriate. The data would be requested before the first user action, but I want it to be first requested after the first user action. It seems like my approach is totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to accomplish appropriate behavior.

```
//model of user actions
val userActions = Observable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).share();//user clicks every second//
//model of my observable with data which supports backpressure
val dataFromServer = Observable.range(1, 10);//data has 10 pages//

dataFromServer
    .doOnNext(it -> System.out.println("Received from server" + it))
    .flatMap(it -> userActions.take(1).ignoreElements().startWith(it), 1)
    .doOnNext(it -> System.out.println("Before data showing" + it))
    .subscribe(showData());
```

Comment: Yep, if you have pagination then the 2-parameter `flatMap` works best.